# IE11 thinks the double dashes in commented code is the end comment tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 I'm getting the error `Unexpected character in comment end. Expected "-->".` because the commented code contains a double dash in the class. Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Example:

```
<!--  
<div class="block--attribute"></div>
-->
```

From this example I'm guessing IE11 thinks the end of the comment is `--a`

Comment: The [HTML5 validator](https://html5.validator.nu/) produces the warning _“The document is not mappable to XML 1.0 due to two consecutive hyphens in a comment.”_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the warning on my side, this is an [HTML5 parser warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh180764(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), this warning can occur as part of the validation that is performed during HTML parsing. These warnings don't necessarily mean a page is broken, but that the provided HTML is invalid per the HTML5 standard.

When using the comment tag, it does not support any standard attributes (such as the class attribute). More information about [Standard Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_comment.asp).

To solve this warning, you could remove the class attribute, code as below:

```
 <!--
     <div ></div>
 -->
```